# urllib2.urlopen wait forever for specific url, though curl, browser get immediately

Tags: python, urllib2

I just used simple code below.

```
urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

but it doesn't return me anything and wait forever. After adding timeout, it just timeout.

I'm testing my api with python. but urllib2.urlopen wait forever for my api, though curl, browser get immediately. urllib can get other url and my api server show me that it return value when python version request it. At least the server tried to return value when python request. It looks like that there are some server side issue. But which part of urllib cause this? How can i fix it?

Comment: @Duniyadnd  something like this http://111.111.111.111:8111/viewAllNodes

Comment: Does it return a keep-alive connection? Firefox etc may be showing partial results while urlopen waits for the connection to be closed?

Comment: @HughBothwell My server return value with 'keep-alive' connection. So I've tried lib which supports keep-alive(I've used urlib3), And Problem solved. Thank you for your help!